# why whitelist url HERE map api still blocking my entered urls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geolocation, here-maps-rest

I whitelist my domain fyipark.com home page to begin as I utilize Here map api for searching citys for a select2 field. It was working great with my exposed keys in production and staging. Then I whitelisted the domain name for the home page as thats where I have  HERE service. I was unable to have my keys in hidden ENV variable as instructions asked to white list domains to protect key so I had entered them as per pic attached. It not working now as its being blocked however 1st question; what does the following instructions mean "Insert values without protocol" as perhaps thats where I'm messing up. I am using here map on a search and map page for location was working great until I whitelisted domain. do I have to also have the exact page domain ie fyipark.com/search for the other servces or can I just whitelist the index page for all other pages?
[image]

[image: entered url]

Answer (score 0):

protocol is the http protocol (so either http:// or https://). It's just saying don't include that. Apart from that I don't have an answer to your second question.

Is it still not working for you? I hope it's just because we have to wait for it to be whitelisted (similar to DNS changes). I just added a new domain and it's not going through so I hope it's just because of that.

Comment: I was able to have it working on home page and on another however on My search page here that map resides it was blocked and this what the url looked like when you search for Edmonton for example  [search Edmonton ](https://fyipark.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=Edmonton%2C%20AB%2C%20Canada&start_date=&end_date=&commit=Search)